# NamedTuple to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, namedtuple

I am working on retrieving metadata from youtube channels and it's videos.

Everything is going fine, but currently I am struggling to put all the information in a `dataframe` which I need. Here is the following code which I am using from this `github` https://gist.github.com/andkamau/0d4e312c97f41a975440a05fd76b1d29

```
import urllib.request
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import namedtuple
import pafy
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame() 
Video = namedtuple("Video", "video_id title duration views thumbnail Description")

def parse_video_div(div):
    video_id = div.get("data-context-item-id", "")
    title = div.find("a", "yt-uix-tile-link").text
    duration = div.find("span", "video-time").contents[0].text
    views = str(div.find("ul", "yt-lockup-meta-info").contents[0].text.rstrip(" views").replace(",", ""))
    img = div.find("img")
    videoDescription = pafy.new("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+video_id)
    thumbnail = "http:" + img.get("src", "") if img else ""
    Description = videoDescription.description
    l = Video(video_id, title, duration, views, thumbnail, Description)
     
     # storing in the dataframe
     
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(Video(video_id, title, duration, views, thumbnail, Description)))
    return Video(video_id, title, duration, views, thumbnail, Description)

def parse_videos_page(page):
    video_divs = page.find_all("div", "yt-lockup-video")
    return [parse_video_div(div) for div in video_divs]

def find_load_more_url(page):
    for button in page.find_all("button"):
        url = button.get("data-uix-load-more-href")
        if url:
            return "http://www.youtube.com" + url

def download_page(url):
    print("Downloading {0}".format(url))
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

def get_videos(username):
    page_url = "http://www.youtube.com/channel/{0}/videos".format(username)
    page = BeautifulSoup(download_page(page_url))
    videos = parse_videos_page(page)
    page_url = find_load_more_url(page)
    while page_url:
        json_data = json.loads(str(download_page(page_url).decode("utf-8")))
        page = BeautifulSoup(json_data.get("content_html", ""))
        videos.extend(parse_videos_page(page))
        page_url = find_load_more_url(BeautifulSoup(json_data.get("load_more_widget_html", "")))
    return videos

if __name__ == "__main__":
    videos = get_videos("UC-M9eLhclbe16sDaxLzc0ng")
    for video in videos:
        print(video)
    print("{0} videos".format(len(videos)))
```

The function `parse_video_div(div)` is having all the information and my `dataframe`. But unfortunately the `dataframe` returns nothing. May be I need to loop the `namedtuple` somehow.

Any lead on how I can achieve my `dataframe` to see my data?

Comment: You aren't returning your dataframe in `parse_video_div`. So you convert video to a dataframe in the variable `df` and then you don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame` goes perfectly with `namedtuple` and actually constructs the columns.

Sample data:

```
In [21]: Video = namedtuple("Video", "video_id title duration views thumbnail De
    ...: scription")
In [22]: In [20]: pd.DataFrame(data=[Video(1, 'Vid Title', 5, 10, 'Thumb',' Des'
    ...: )])
Out[22]: 
   video_id      title  duration  views thumbnail Description
0         1  Vid Title         5     10     Thumb         Des
```

Since your function is not actually returning the `df` and not utilizing it anywhere else in the code, how are you sure that it is empty?

**Update**

You just need to edit the return of `parse_video_div` to return a `pd.DataFrame` and concatenate the list into a single `pd.DataFrame` in `get_videos` function.

Here are the edits highlighted.

```
def parse_video_div(div):


    #####
    return pd.DataFrame(data=[Video(video_id, title, duration, views, thumbnail, Description)])
    # shorter version
    # return pd.DataFrame(data=[l])

def get_videos(username):
    ####
    videos_df = pd.concat(videos, ignore_index=True)
    return videos_df # return the DataFrame
```

You need a concantenation function in the end. in the `parse_page_div`, you can return any `pd.DataFrame` input, let that be `dict`, `pd.Series`, `namedtuple`, or even a list. In this example, I chose a `pd.DataFrame` to ease things, however, in terms of performance, it can add a few milliseconds to your processing.

Comment: I am struggling to put all the data in one `dataframe` in the function `parse_video_div` and return it. So that I can use the `dataframe` later for further data analysis. @iDrwish

Comment: @Jazz Check the updated answer, I believe it addresses your point.

Comment: sorry for the late reply as I was running the changes you suggested. It worked magically!!! Thank you so much! :) I have marked it as a corrected answer :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I've always explicitly used `pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=Record._fields)`, but now I know I can do it shorter. Bit surprised the docs don't specify this as an option, so may submit a PR to pandas to include it more clearly